# DB of Lenel OnGuard 7.2 (Under MsSQL 2012 ) how to extract attendance from the DB for 3d party app

Tags: sql-server, database

Database of Lenel OnGuard 7.2 (Under MsSQL 2012 ) how to extract attendance from the DB for 3d party app.

What im trying to do is take employees attendance. Lenel seem complex and so far i could not find some resources except for one in [Lenel with SQL](https://www.dbrown.me/2015/06/30/lenel-onguard-and-sql/)

Please if some is familiar with lanel db schema enlighten me.

EDIT:

Im trying to generate a report which have these details in

Date---------Card No--Dept----Shift--------Time(in - Out)

6/7/2017----55555----MGMT---NoS------6/7/2017 7:3:57
6/7/2017----55555----MGMT---NoS------6/7/2017 17:3:16
6/7/2017----77777----SOFT---NoS------6/7/2017 9:16:39
6/7/2017----77777----SOFT---NoS------6/7/2017 12:9:45
6/7/2017----77777----SOFT---NoS------6/7/2017 12:47:29
6/7/2017----77777----SOFT---NoS------6/7/2017 20:27:44

Edited

I managed to modify your code to

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) AS  'ReportDate',
ev.cardnum          AS  'Cardnumber',
dt.name             AS  'Department',
ev.Event_time_utc   AS  'Time'

FROM accesscontrol.dbo.events ev        WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN accesscontrol.dbo.UDFEMP ud  WITH (NOLOCK) ON ev.EmpID   =   ud.ID
INNER JOIN accesscontrol.dbo.dept   dt  WITH (NOLOCK) ON ud.dept    =   dt.ID

WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, ev.Event_time_utc))) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
ORDER BY cardnum desc
```

However it seems the results is to large. I think there is something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database you are looking for is:

```
[AccessControl].[dbo].[Events]
```

From there on, you can JOIN EMPID on ID in EMP database to get user firstname lastname and you can get the reader by joining Machine on PanelID in READER database.

EDIT: The blow query I made will show you the last 10 badge => reader events in the database.

```
    SELECT TOP 10 
    GETDATE()           AS  'ReportDate',
    ev.cardnum          AS  'Cardnumber',
    dt.name             AS  'Department',
    ev.Event_time_utc   AS  'TimeStamp'

    FROM accesscontrol.dbo.events ev        WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN accesscontrol.dbo.UDFEMP ud  WITH (NOLOCK) ON ev.EmpID   =   ud.ID
    INNER JOIN accesscontrol.dbo.dept   dt  WITH (NOLOCK) ON ud.dept    =   dt.ID

    ORDER BY 'TimeStamp' desc
```

Comment: Thank you Vasil for your answer. I still cant get my head around it. How to select all the cards used today in and Out. Question updated.

Comment: I have edited my post. I dont see any "Shift" tab or option anywhere in the Lenel, but this query should give you the idea of what you can get from the database.

Comment: Thank you very much @VasilSvilenovNikolov Your answer differently is helping a lot in solving my issue. Question been edited.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, you can mark it as Answer to help others. About your result being too big, is because you get all the Events, and people can check in more then once, if you for example do `SELECT DISTINCT` and remove `Time` from the statement, you will see all the badges that have entered the building at that day, instead of all the badge in events for that day.